# Scale a SQL geography polygon

Tags: r, sql-server, t-sql, sqlgeography, dotspatial

Is it possible to scale a SQL geography polygon like what is being done [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/scaling-a-feature.htm)?

Ideally I'd like to add a buffer of x meters either to the inside or outside of the original geography in SQL.

I also have [DotSpatial](https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial) and R available if a SQL option is not possible.

[image: example of what I'm trying to do]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `STBuffer()` method does what you want. Like so:

```
select geo.STBuffer(5)
from dbo.myTable;
```

Where the input to the method will be in units that are specific to the SRID of the geography instance being operated on. If you're not sure, consult `sys.spatial_reference_systems` with the SRID of your data.